# ModX Evo pub_date placeholder not displaying

Tags: modx, modx-evolution, modx-templates

I am displaying the `pub_date` for a resource inside a Ditto chunk, eg:

```
[+pub_date:date=`%B %d, %Y`+]
```

And this works fine.

But when I try to put it in a template, eg:

```
[*pub_date:date=`%B %d, %Y`*]
```

it doesnt work.

Doesn anyone know what Im doing wrong or of a better way of doing this?

(This is in Evo 1.0.4)

Answer (score 0):

You have to install PHx for that. It is currently maintained at https://github.com/Temus/PHx